# how to get option labels and insert into array using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I need all option labels in array in javascript.

html code:

```
<select name="name" id="id">
  <option value="val1">lab1</option>
  <option value="val2">lab2</option>
  <option value="val3">lab3</option>
  <option value="val4">lab4</option>
  <option value="val5">lab5</option>
</select>
```

This code doesnt work for me:

I want to have `lab1`, `lab2`... in array. Number of option isnt the same all the time. How can i do taht?

Comment: What code does not work for you?

Comment: i just dont know how to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var labels = $("#id>option").map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
//["lab1","lab2","lab3","lab4","lab5"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` method, try the following:

```
var lab = $('#id option').map(function(){
               return $(this).text() // or return this.InnerHTML
          })
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FqzC5/)

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
var arr = $( '#id' ).children().map(function () {
    return $( this ).text();
}).get();
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/HXgE6/ (open console to view results)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#id').children().map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TAGx7/) (open console to view array)